# Using asset pipeline to include a javascript file in rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I added a simple Javascript file to my rails project `beer_background.js` and put the file in `app/assets/javascripts`  I want to load the `beer_background.js` when the `application.html.erb` is rendered, so I put the following line in the `application.html.erb`

`<%= javascript_include_tag('beer_background.js') %>`

However this is causing the rails app to produce error that looks like the following.

[image: error]

**Update**

*application.js*

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require d3
```

Comment: What does your `application.js` file look like?

Comment: just added the `application.js`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to use `javascript_include_tag`. Having the files in the location you do and `//= require_tree .` in your `application.js` should be enough.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

> The require_tree directive tells Sprockets to recursively include all JavaScript files in the specified directory into the output. These paths must be specified relative to the manifest file. You can also use the require_directory directive which includes all JavaScript files only in the directory specified, without recursion.

Comment: Joe that's what I thought too.  Does it make a difference that I manually added the JS file to the `javascripts` directory?  Or should I have done something like `rails g my.js` to add the file to the project?

Comment: Is your JS file not being loaded? You should be able to tell if it loaded by checking the development console and viewing sources.

Answer (score 1):

You should include your javascript file from within the application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require d3
//= require beer_background
```

or use `//= require_tree .` which will include all assets under the current directory